# Terrafrom Dynamic block with tags

Tags: azure, terraform

```
Terraform Variable file 
    ---- Variable File ----
    variable "vm_tags" {
    type = map(string)
    default = {
    "owner" = "abc",
    "Env"   = "Prod"
     }
     }

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
---- main.tf ----
     dynamic "tags" {
     for_each = var.vm_tags
     content{
     tags.key = tags.value
        }
     }
   
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the error i am getting while terraform plan

```
    Error: Argument or block definition required
```

on main.tf line 45, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "myvm":
tags.key = tags.value

```
An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.

Tags count will be dynamic
```

Comment: Corrected coe but still some other erro 
 dynamic "tags" {
   for_each = var.vm_tags
   content = {
   tags.key = tags.value
        }
   }
Error :- Error: Unsupported block type

  on main.tf line 42, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "myvm":
  42:    dynamic "tags" {

Blocks of type "tags" are not expected here.

Comment: What is your purpose when you use the dynamic block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to make a dynamic block here. Terraform expects `tags` to be a map, and your tags variable is a `map`. You can just use the map directly via:
`tags = var.vm_tags`

Comment: Thanks Mark for your suggestion